# Pandas - Pivot Table generated from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to generate a pivot table structure but only from two columns of data. What I have is this general DataFrame;

`df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Australia', 'Japan', 'Brazil'], 'code': ['R1', 'R2', 'R3']})`

and what I am trying to achieve is have the `name` field in both the columns and the index, and the values to the the concatenated strings from the `code` field. This will result in a DataFrame with shape (3, 3). Essentially having in the `Australia` row and `Japan` column the value of `R1-R2` and in the `Brazil` row and `Australia` column the value of `R3-R1`.

I tried using this function but I am not sure the `pivot_table` can take the same value in the index and columns.

`pd.pivot_table(df, values='code', index=['name'], columns=['name'], aggfunc=lambda x: '-'.join(x))`

Essentially, the output should be of this form (although maybe with index and column names) and not manually generated;

```
data = {'Australia': ['R1-R1', 'R2-R1', 'R3-R1'],
        'Japan': ['R1-R2', 'R2-R2', 'R3-R2'],
        'Brazil': ['R1-R3', 'R2-R3', 'R3-R3']}

df_result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Australia', 'Japan', 'Brazil'], index=['Australia', 'Japan', 'Brazil'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, you could do this:

```
df1 = df.assign(key=1).merge(df.assign(key=1), how='outer',on='key',suffixes=('','_c'))

df1 = df1.drop('key',axis=1)

df1['value'] = df1['code'] + '-' + df1['code_c']

df2 = df1.drop(['code','code_c'],axis=1)

df_result = df2.set_index(['name','name_c']).unstack()

df_result.columns = df_result.columns.droplevel()

print(df_result)
```

Output:

```
name_c    Australia Brazil  Japan
name                             
Australia     R1-R1  R1-R3  R1-R2
Brazil        R3-R1  R3-R3  R3-R2
Japan         R2-R1  R2-R3  R2-R2
```